# Tag Badge tracking suggestion doesn't account for negative score

Tags: bug, tag-badges

This is very minor, but it seems that the tag badge tracker doesn't recognise when you've gotten negative score in a tag. Take a look at what it's suggesting as my next badge:

[image: Screenshot]

I believe it's treating the -12 score as if it's 0, so since I have 3 answers in discussion that seems like a more viable option as my next target even though I'm actually closer to the requirements for questions.

If it's that answers get that much more weight it seems a little lopsided since I could have a lot of poor quality answers without having made any good posts but most users won't be hitting close to 100 points in only a few answers and there's no way for them to get *negative* answers. But even if answers are seen as more important, it seems odd for 3 answers to override a significantly negative score.

Comment: You know, I could find anything on MSE for how this is done.  I'm curious now too, so I posted [a question on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264037/how-is-the-closest-tag-badge-determined)

Comment: Please see my answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263829/in-next-badge-selection-why-does-epic-with-2-50-sort-ahead-of-illuminator-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, at least in the way the tracking was designed.  You are closer in terms of the number of answers to the discussion badge than the questions badge despite your negative score.

Closeness to completion is based on the sum of each individual progress bar, specifically [by the amount each bar is filled on the screen truncated to a whole percentage point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263829/in-next-badge-selection-why-does-epic-with-2-50-sort-ahead-of-illuminator-with/263865#263865).  A negative score doesn't retract from the progress bar's fill amount, so **you are correct that negative scores are implicitly counted as 0**.  Which is why your negative scoring tag is ranked closer to completion than your other tag.

Comment: That seems like too much weight to me if that is the case, since previously I was below -20 and it was still my recommended badge.

Comment: Yeah this weighting is just a guess (it might not even be linear).  But the point stands that you are closer in one regard and further in the other.

Comment: Oh I agree that might be the case, I should probably make that clearer in my post.

Comment: +1 Thanks for fixing it and you may want to elaborate your answer as my answer is on the other Meta.SE. So, cross site dupe is not issue. Thanks for the link to my answer.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I missed your edit. It's looks ok. Blame 'cache' may be.