# How select next tag badge view is sorted

Tags: discussion, user-interface, tag-badges

When I select the next tag badge to track I see the following window:

[image: Select next tag badge]

So each tag badge has four numbers:

- **s**: earned score
- **S**: required score
- **a**: posted answers
- **A**: required answers

I'm curious how this view is sorted. My best guess is that sorting key is calculated according to the formula: `floor(50*(min(s/S, 1)+min(a/A, 1)))` and when this yields equal result, the badges are sorted alphabetically. This algorithm is almost consistent with what I see, but one badge is misplaced (it's not on the screenshot). Does anybody know what's the real sorting algorithm?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list/253709#253709

Comment: Sorted by percentage complete (rounded to an integer) then by tag name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And how is the percentage calculated?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Percentage complete = min(floor((s/S) * 100), 100) + min(floor((a/A) * 100), 100), I think. So the two bars are 0-100, and their sum informs the sort.

Comment: Very related: [Tag Badge tracking suggestion doesn't account for negative score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303058/4320665).   And an MSE duplicate: [How is the closest tag badge determined?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264037/280467)

Comment: @Deduplicator it's based off of the amount the green progress bars are filled (using floor math to get integer percentages).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's a pretty bad formula, and it gives 200% complete.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: The devil is in the detaills.

Comment: @Deduplicator more details.  User [Hacker Karma actually inspected the resulting HTML](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263865/280467) for the details.  AFAIK he's correct.

Comment: @Deduplicator: But that's only used when sorting. The two CSS bars use the 0-100 floored percentage.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure. Still, wouldn't `min(0, floor(100*s/S), floor(100*a/A))` make more sense, or at least something emphasizing the lower percentage over the higher a bit? Maybe something more like `100*(x/(1-y)+y/(1-x))/(1/(1-y)+1/(1-x))` (Substitute 100x resp. 100y when one of them is not between 0 and 1, exclusive. 0 resp. 100 if both are.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: I forgot about `0` being a minimum. I think it is `max(0, min(100, floor(100*s/S))` and `max(0, min(100, floor(100*a/A))` for the CSS progress bars, and the sorting is simply the sum of those two integers (with badge name as the tiebreaker).

Comment: @Deduplicator: at any rate, I didn't build this, I'm just communicating my observations. I'm fine with how it works right now.